# Jboss Seam JSESSIONID Cookie-Settings

Tags: security, cookies, jboss, seam, jsessionid

I wanted to know, how I can override the jsessionid-cookie setting such as httpoly, secure and so on.
I didn't find any setting or other easy possibility to set these things.
Could it be something in the `web.xml` under session-config or can I add the settings via an servlet filter?

What would you suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In web.xml file,

```
<session-config>
        <cookie-config>
           <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

You can see in

- http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1041
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beash.html

Comment: unfortunately, this is not an option for seam versions with http-servlet specification < 3.